# Text files: writing on sepates lines

Tags: python, file

Propose we have this simple function:

```
X():
   A = open("File.txt", "w")
   A.write("cbcobcebviue")
   A.close
```

In the file we would see "cbcobcebviue". My questions is how do we write on separate lines without over-writing producing something like this,
aaaa (Line1)
aaxsxs (Line2)
aaaaa (Line3)
NOT aaaaaaxsxsaaaaa (Line1)?
I've been searching for HOURS and I can't find any clear answers.

Comment: You'll probably want to add a language tag if you want anyone to see this..

Comment: So you want to *append* to the file instead of *overwrite* it.  Whatever language/framework/etc. you're using should have some means of distinguishing between the two.  Check the documentation.

Comment: I've only started learning Python a month. I don't know this section well which is why I'm asking.

Comment: Thank you. Just solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a new line character `'\n'` to your string:

```
A = open("File.txt", "w")
A.write("cbcobcebviue\n")
#                     ^
A.close()
```

> newline, also known as a line ending, end of line (EOL), or line
>   break, is a special character or sequence of characters signifying the
>   end of a line of text and the start of a new line

So as in your example, you would do:

```
A = open("File.txt", "w")
A.write("aaaa\naaxsxs\naaaaa\n")
#             ^       ^      ^ 
A.close()
```

Which would be written in your file as:

```
aaaa
aaxsxs
aaaaa
```

Comment: Yes! This is what I was looking for! THANKS YOU :D!

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open):

> The most commonly-used values of mode are 'r' for reading, 'w' for writing (truncating the file if it already exists), and 'a' for
>   appending (which on some Unix systems means that all writes append to
>   the end of the file regardless of the current seek position).

So, probably what you'd want is:

```
A = open("File.txt", "a")
A.write("cbcobcebviue")
A.close
```

Note, you'd want to put a `\n` at the end of your string to insert a line break.